# How to solve 'Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!'?

Tags: react-native, expo, node-modules, yarnpkg, fastlane

**When I tried**

```
expo build:ios
```

**I got an error**

```
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/spaceship1592360646_8184_70175802335700.log
Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!
Reason: Unknown reason, raw: "Could not receive latest API key from App Store Connect, this might be a server issue."
Error: Reason: Unknown reason, raw: "Could not receive latest API key from App Store Connect, this might be a server issue."
    at runAction (/Users/user_name/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/expo-cli/src/appleApi/fastlane.ts:28:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at authenticate (/Users/user_name/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/expo-cli/src/appleApi/authenticate.ts:47:40)
    at Context.ensureAppleCtx (/Users/user_name/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/expo-cli/src/credentials/context.ts:63:24)
    at IOSBuilder.bestEffortAppleCtx (/Users/user_name/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/build/ios/IOSBuilder.ts:112:14)
    at IOSBuilder.prepareCredentials (/Users/user_name/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/build/ios/IOSBuilder.ts:137:5)
    at IOSBuilder.run (/Users/user_name/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/build/ios/IOSBuilder.ts:57:7)
    at IOSBuilder.command (/Users/user_name/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/build/BaseBuilder.ts:27:7)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/Users/user_name/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/expo-cli/src/exp.ts:80:7)
```

**diagnostics**

```
Expo CLI 3.21.5 environment info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.15.5
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 12.18.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.22.4 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.14.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.4 AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156
      Xcode: 11.0/11A420a - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      expo: ^37.0.0 => 37.0.11 
      react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
      react-dom: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
      react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz => 0.61.4 
      react-native-web: ^0.11.7 => 0.11.7 
      react-navigation: ^4.3.4 => 4.3.4
```

My expo version is the latest and two factor authentication is enabled.

I would appreciate it if you could give me any advice.

Comment: Maybe try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56133882/13107433)

Comment: @高鵬翔 Thank you as always. I tried to build again closing virus buster, but nothing has changed :(

Comment: Ensure that you're running the build command on the desktop rather than remotely. The system needs to open a desktop dialog to obtain your credentials.